# A const value is changed when updating another var during a loop Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm facing a bit of a weird situation and I can't spot the cause. I'm my server update order endpoint, I can either receive an orderState or an updatedOrder to update MongoDB record `var { orderState, updatedOrder } = req.body;`.
As I'll be modifying `updatedOrder` in a `for` loop to update MongoDB, I also assign the received updatedOrder to a constant to be passed later on to Neo4j to do same updates and create relationships, as `const modifiedOrder = req.body.updatedOrder;` .

With an if/else statement I either update MongoDB Order record `state` parameter or the entire Order record.
In the second case, when `updatedOrder.cart` item `state` property is found to be `'Refund requested'`, and accordingly to the property `isPromotion` to be `true` or `false` I first update `Product` and `Promotion` records, then update `updatedOrder` cart item state value to `Refunded`, in the mentioned `for` loop.

Then after the `for` loop I update the `Order` record with the updated `updatedOrder`.

The problem is that after the first loop `modifiedOrder` is also updated, so when sent to Neo4j cart item state is not `'Refund requested'` but `'Refunded'`.

How can it be that `const modifiedOrder` value is changed when modifying `var updatedOrder`? Even dough they get the initial value from `req.body.updatedOrder` a const should keep the first assigned value right?

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
var { orderState, updatedOrder } = req.body;
    const modifiedOrder = req.body.updatedOrder;
    console.log(
      '1> Mongoose updatedOrder received modifiedOrder.cart is',
      modifiedOrder.cart
    ); // correct 

if (orderState) {

...

} else if (updatedOrder) {

for (var i = 0; i < updatedOrder.cart.length; i++) {
          console.log(
            `LOOP> Mongoose updatedOrder before loop ${i} modifiedOrder.cart is
            ${modifiedOrder.cart}`
          ); 
          // at 1st loop (i = 0) CORRECT 1st item state is "Refund requested"
          // at second loop (i = 1) WRONG 1st item state is now "Refunded"

          var cartItem = JSON.parse(updatedOrder.cart[i]);
          if (cartItem.state == 'Refund requested') {
            if (cartItem.isPromotion == false) {
              await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
                cartItem.id,
                {
                  $inc: { soldQuantity: -1, availableQuantity: 1 },
                },
                {
                  session: session,
                  new: true,
                },
                null
              )
                .clone()
                .exec()
                .then((result) => {
                  console.log(
                    'Mongoose Order.updateOrder / Product.update Inventory updated successfully for product:',
                    result.id
                  );
                  if (result != null) {
                    cartItem.state = 'Refunded';
                    totalRefundAmount += result.price;
                  } else {
                    cartItem.state = 'Not refunded';

                  }
                  return;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log(
                      'Mongoose Order.updateOrder / Product.update error: ',
                      error
                    );
                    cartItem.state = 'Not refunded';
                    throw error;
                  }
                });
            } else if (cartItem.isPromotion == true) {
              await Promotion.findByIdAndUpdate(
                cartItem.id,
                {
                  $inc: { soldQuantity: -1, availableQuantity: 1 },
                },
                {
                  session: session,
                  new: true,
                }
              )
                .clone()
                .exec()
                .then((result) => {
                  if (result != null) {
                    totalRefundAmount += result.price;
                    cartItem.state = 'Refunded';
                    console.log(
                      'Mongoose Order.updateOrder / Promotion.update Inventory updated successfully for promotion:',
                      result
                    );
                  } else {
                    cartItem.state = 'Not refunded';
                  }
                  return;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log(
                      'Mongoose Order.updateOrder / Promotion.update error: ',
                      error
                    );
                    cartItem.state = 'Not refunded';
                    throw error;
                  }
                });
            }
          }
          updatedOrder.cart[i] = JSON.stringify(cartItem);
        }



...
}
```

before 1st loop 1st item is "Refund requested":

```
LOOP> Mongoose updatedOrder before loop 0 modifiedOrder.cart is
            {"createdOnDate":1638894572905,"name":"testProduct","brand":"someBrand","price":12,"description":"description","category":"Safety and locks","city":"Bologna","region":"Emilia-Romagna","country":"Italy","vendor":"testShop","vendorId":"OrderTestShop","barcode":"some","imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9","fullImages":[],"thumbNails":[],"minimumStock":10,"availableQuantity":10,"soldQuantity":0,"isPromotion":false,"totalRating":0,"ratings":0,"_id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","createdAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.399Z","updatedAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.399Z","__v":0,"averageRating":0,"id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","isRecommendation":true,"state":"Refund requested"},{"createdOnDate":1638894572905,"productId":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","name":"testPromotion","brand":"someBrand","price":12,"description":"new description","category":"Safety and locks","city":"Bologna","region":"Emilia-Romagna","country":"Italy","vendor":"testShop","vendorId":"OrderTestShop","barcode":"some","imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9","fullImages":[],"thumbNails":[],"minimumStock":10,"availableQuantity":10,"soldQuantity":0,"isPromotion":true,"totalRating":0,"ratings":0,"_id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de4","createdAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.467Z","updatedAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.467Z","__v":0,"averageRating":0,"id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de4","isRecommendation":true,"state":"Bought"}
```

after first loop 1st item is "Refunded":

```
LOOP> Mongoose updatedOrder before loop 1 modifiedOrder.cart is
            {"createdOnDate":1638894572905,"name":"testProduct","brand":"someBrand","price":12,"description":"description","category":"Safety and locks","city":"Bologna","region":"Emilia-Romagna","country":"Italy","vendor":"testShop","vendorId":"OrderTestShop","barcode":"some","imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9","fullImages":[],"thumbNails":[],"minimumStock":10,"availableQuantity":10,"soldQuantity":0,"isPromotion":false,"totalRating":0,"ratings":0,"_id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","createdAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.399Z","updatedAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.399Z","__v":0,"averageRating":0,"id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","isRecommendation":true,"state":"Refunded"},{"createdOnDate":1638894572905,"productId":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de2","name":"testPromotion","brand":"someBrand","price":12,"description":"new description","category":"Safety and locks","city":"Bologna","region":"Emilia-Romagna","country":"Italy","vendor":"testShop","vendorId":"OrderTestShop","barcode":"some","imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9","fullImages":[],"thumbNails":[],"minimumStock":10,"availableQuantity":10,"soldQuantity":0,"isPromotion":true,"totalRating":0,"ratings":0,"_id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de4","createdAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.467Z","updatedAt":"2022-11-08T08:00:30.467Z","__v":0,"averageRating":0,"id":"636a0c9e8145999716d71de4","isRecommendation":true,"state":"Bought"}
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  key: 'value1'
};

const objShallowCopy = obj;
const objDeepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj.key = 'value2';

console.log('objShallowCopy: ', objShallowCopy);
console.log('objDeepCopy: ', objDeepCopy);
```

Comment: HI and thanks for answering. yeap the const in js still gets me at times lol. Still just to make sure, I'm changing the value of `updatedOrder` which changes `req.body.updatedOrder` as well, thus `modifiedOrder ` gets changed as well. Correct ?? I thought about it, but thought that `req.body.updatedOrder` wouldn't get modified so ruled it out. Should have known better.. I do now! lol

Comment: Correct, `updatedOrder` and `modifiedOrder` and `req.body.updatedOrder` all reference (point to) the same location in memory (in this case, an "order" object). Declaring something with `const` ensure that what value/object it references cannot be changed but it but it doesn't prevent changes to the values within that referenced object.

Comment: To phrase it differently, `const` creates an immutable _binding_, not an immutable value.